# Iterating over a multivaluemap from arraylist values java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have some keys in an arraylist. Now, I want to search for values from a multivaluemap by passing those keys and saving the value in a list. What would be the best way to approach it. Thanks.

```
MultiValueMap<String,String>subcountyid = new MultiValueMap<String,String>();
subcountyid = d.getSubcountyid();

ArrayList<String>subcountynames = (ArrayList<String>) subcounties.get(county_id);
```

So, basically all my keys are in the subcountynames arraylist and I want to search through my subcountyid map for the value of each keys.  How should i approach this situation.

Comment: is this spring, Apache commons or your own Collection?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ- Apache commons

Comment: What is `county_id`, and whats wrong with current way of fetching the list of country names?

Comment: @nullpointer:- Lets say when you pass countyid = 47, it searches the map and gets the values in a list which is my subcountynames and the names are stored in a list. Now, I want to pass each value from subcountynames and search another map

Comment: so whats the harm in iterating through the list of sub country names that you've just obtained?